# Ionic 2 : Moving config properties into the bootstrap

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

Before beta.8 version, I have a working service which acts as my HTTP service.

```
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/log-in/log-in.html',
  providers: [httpService]
})

...

this.httpService.testService("VariablesToPass").subscribe(
    data => {this.results = data.results; console.log(data);},
    //err => this.logError(err),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('Invoked Login Service Complete')
 );
```

After the new version, configs have to move into the bootstrap, thus in my js i implemented the following :

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/log-in/log-in.html'
})

export class LoginPage {

...

}
ionicBootstrap(LoginPage, [httpService], {});
```

in which throws me errors like:

[image]

Using

```
ionicBootstrap(LoginPage, [httpService], {});
```

or

```
ionicBootstrap(LoginPage, [httpService]);
```

gives the same error result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ionicBootstrap` must be used only in your former `@App`, not in a former `@Page`, inject `httpService` there, not in `LoginPage`.

In your LoginPage leave the provider registration. Also, beware of your naming convention, it doesn't look right, you are using the same name for the service and its instance. It should be like this:

```
    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'build/pages/log-in/log-in.html',
      providers: [HttpService]
    })
    class LoginPage {

      constructor ( private httpService : HttpService) {}

}
```

<sub>also, it's beta 8, not RC</sub>

Comment: constructor ( private httpService : HttpService) {} doesnt work. Throws syntax error instead. and thanks, edited the question.

Comment: can you post LoginPage and httpService classes?

Comment: `constructor ( public httpService : HttpService) {}` or `constructor ( private httpService : HttpService) { this.httpService = httpService;}`